# Artifactory directory contains dots, can't resolve dependencies with Gradle 6.5

Tags: gradle, artifactory

Using 5.4.1, Gradle was able to resolve dependencies of the form:

```
dependencies {
  implementation "my.groupname:my-project-name:${version}"
}
```

where the dependency artifacts were stored in jFrog artifactory under:

```
//my.artifactory.url/my-repo/my.groupname/my-project-name/
```

If I upgrade my wrapper to 6.5, Gradle isn't able to resolve the dependencies any longer. If the setup were completely under my control, I'd move the artifacts to:

```
//my.artifactory.url/my-repo/my/groupname/my-project-name/
```

and be on my merry way. Unfortunately, it's not, so I can't. Is there a straightforward way to workaround it in my project without changing the structure in artifactory? I'm using maven dependency resolution, as well as the id com.jfrog.artifactory plugin at version 4.16.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** (*The original answer only worked on a hot cache*) I was able to resolve the issue by adding an entry to the repositories and also hacking the dependencies a bit section of build.gradle:

```
repositories {
  // ... other repositories
  maven {
    url "my.artifactory.url/my-repo/"
    artifactUrls "my.artifactory.url/my-repo/my.groupname"
    credentials {
      username = "${artifactory_user}"
      password = "${artifactory_password}"
    }
    metadataSources {
      artifact()
      ignoreGradleMetadataRedirection()
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation ".:my-project-name:${version}"
}
```

Initially, I had also included `mavenPom()` in the metadataSources, but there was an incorrect pom.xml on the other end, so I had to remove it (the groupId in pom.xml was missing).